# Create a synthetic dataset from the measures of spread

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, python, data-visualization, descriptive-statistics

I have certain measures of spread (p50, p66, p75, p80, p90, p95, p98, p99, p99.9, p99.99, p100, Median, Mean, Min, Max)as my attributes. Can I regenerate a data distribution from these?

Use case: I wish to create violin plots for the above distribution but I cannot do so with just the above attributes

Comment: Do you have any percentiles below 50?

Comment: No. I have the min value though

Comment: Then you are proverbially screwed. You will have to make some assumptions regarding the lower half of the data.